# Open a report with data from a generated RecordSet

Tags: ms-access

I'm fairly new to Access, VBA, and reporting. What I am trying to do is to take the results from a dynamic query that I created and open a report using that data.

My basic setup so far is a table with data that is entered by the user. At the end of the month they're supposed to generate a report. To generate this report I set up a form with VBA behind it to generate a query based on their input. Once that query is run I have it set to open the report.

Currently I have not figured out how to use that RecordSet as the data source for the report.

Could anyone please help me out with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I tend to handle situations like this is to create a saved query in Access, base the Report on that saved query, and then just update the `.SQL` property of the QueryDef object before opening the report.

For example, for the report [MyReport] I would create a saved query named [DataForMyReport] with some dummy SQL Statement in it. Then when the time comes to run the report for a given query I would just do

```vbs
Dim cdb as DAO.Database, qdf as DAO.QueryDef
Set cdb = CurrentDb
Set qdf = cdb.QueryDefs("DataForMyReport")
qdf.SQL = strNewQueryToUse  ' replace the SQL statement with the new one
Set qdf = Nothing
DoCmd.OpenReport "MyReport"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do 1 of 3 things:

1) Create a saved query and use that query as the report's RecordSource.  The data in the query will change, but the query name will not.  When the report opens, it will pull in the current results of the saved query.  This is definitely the easiest way to do it.

2) When you open the report, set its RecordSource in code.  I don't see a need to do this.

3) If you find it absolutely necessary to create a query on the fly and the name of that query might change, you can pass it as an OpenArgs.  I wouldn't recommend this, though.

Comment: It's a query created within the VBA script. It's not just a static query.

Comment: But you can **save** it using VBA, and give it the same name every time.